# How to make a query replace column if exist using sql-server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query as the below one:

```
alter table [toolDB].[dbo].[esn_sho] add esn_umts_sho_relation_key as Convert(nvarchar(50),[utrancell])+'_'+Convert(nvarchar(50),[utranrelation])
```

So All I need I want to replace `esn_umts_sho_relation_key` column if exist...

As I got this error:

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'esn_umts_sho_relation_key' in table 'toolDB.dbo.esn_sho' is specified more than once
```

I tired to use the below code but it's doen't work:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (alter table [toolDB].[dbo].[esn_sho] add esn_umts_sho_relation_key as Convert(nvarchar(50),[utrancell])+'_'+Convert(nvarchar(50),[utranrelation]))
```

It gives me this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'alter'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'
```

So I want to add `If Exist` in this query any one knows how to solve this prolem...

The column I already exist in the table ,but I want to replace it if exist to `escape` from this error...

Comment: Hi, do you have a alternative if it doesn't work (error is thrown)? You could try a try catch block in SQL : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Also, may I ask why you need to insert a column into a table if there is a chance that it exists?
Are you migrating from one database to other?

Comment: @Omkar Look I'll dicuss you my whole case... I am just creating a database based on excel files... after that I make visualize on the database after created and create scripts using python, pandas(function), and some queries, So every time I push those `excels` files to the `sql` I replace all the tables, and If I add add another columns So I'll replace the old columns with the new column with the new values, as this query is one of my queries

Comment: @Omkar as the excels file have a lot of data as there's a limitation in the excel file, If I visualize the excel file directly I'lll get errors, So I have to push all data I have to the database and start visualize from the database instead of the excel file.. So every time I import all data to excel file I want to replace it with the old data.. that's all... this is why I need to replace the table with the new table use to the new values in the tab;e but It's should have the same columns every time using this process

Comment: If you are simply overwriting all data, just drop the tables. You will require more time to check whether the data exists, if not then insert, vs just recreating the table again.

Comment: Also, I would suggest you don't write the data again and again from scratch, but instead of importing the data into excel and doing all of this manually, figure out a way to get the data from the source of the excel and populate the db real time. It will automate things for you and make your life easier.

Comment: @Omkar that's What I am searching for I want to create a query by helping python pandas that's drops all tables in the data base and start to run the script I have created this query `Delete All Columns"
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = "DROP TABLE ?` but didn't work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208391/discussion-between-mahmoud-al-haroon-and-omkar).

Answer (score 2):

```
IF COL_LENGTH('TableName', 'ColumnName') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    -- Column Exists
    -- here you can put your cond...
END


IF COL_LENGTH('[toolDB].[dbo].[esn_sho]', 'esn_umts_sho_relation_key') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    -- Column Exists
    alter table [toolDB].[dbo].[esn_sho] add esn_umts_sho_relation_key as Convert(nvarchar(50),[utrancell])+'_'+Convert(nvarchar(50),[utranrelation])---Put your condition in proper way...
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DatabaseName  where ColumnName = @YourParameter)
BEGIN
You Can Write Alter Query Here
END
ELSE
BEGIN
You Can Set Here AN Else Condition/Optional
END
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this particular issue, you can use the system tables. Try this

```
SELECT * 
    FROM sys.all_objects obj
    JOIN sys.all_columns col ON obj.object_id = col.object_id
WHERE 
    obj.Name = @YourTableName
    AND col.Name = @YourColumnName
```

This will give you the columns in your table if it exists. You can use this to make your decision about what you would do if it exists/doesn't exist.